# start_track parameter cant be over 25 in like-list-player-widget

Tags: soundcloud

If I generate the widget of someone´s like-list e.g. [here](https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/users/91278145/favorites&auto_play=false&hide_related=false&show_comments=true&show_user=true&show_reposts=false&visual=true): and add the parameter "`&start_track=`" I can only access the first 24 tracks of this playlist. If I set a higher start_track over 24, I always land on the same track. Is this a bug? What can I do to access e.g. track 40 in a like-list?

Answer (score 1):

In order for the playlist widget to be performant it only loads 25 first tracks – adding more as user scrolls down or reaches the end of current 25-tracks set. This means that if you set `start_track` to anything more than 25, it won't have what to play yet.

We could check for this param and load according to the offset we need, but we don't right now. I'll create a story for this and update the answer if we get to fix this.